# Should I dinamically allocate memory for a numpy array that could be created at runtime in cython?

Tags: python, cython

This runs smoothly and fast:

```
solexa_scores = '!"#$%&' + "'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHI"

cdef np.ndarray[np.uint32_t, ndim=2] sums = np.zeros(shape=(length, len(solexa_scores)+33), dtype=np.uint32) 

cdef bytes line
cdef str decoded_line
cdef int counter=0 # Useful to know if it's the 3rd or 4th line of the current sequence in fastq.
with gzip.open(file_in, "rb") as f:
    for line in f:
    
        if counter%4==0: # first line of the sequence (obtain tile info)
            counter=0
    
        elif counter%3==0: # 3rd line of the sequence (obtain the qualities)
            decoded_line = line.decode('utf-8')
            for n in range(len(decoded_line)): #     enumerate(line.decode('utf-8')):
                sums[n, ord(decoded_line[n])] +=1
                
        counter+=1
```

Here the numpy ndarray *sums* contains the results.

However, instead of a single numpy array, I need an *unknown* number of arrays in a dictionary (named *tiles*) and this is the code that should accomplish my goal:

```
solexa_scores = '!"#$%&' + "'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHI"

cdef dict tiles = {} # each tile will have it's own 'sums' numpy array

cdef bytes line
cdef str decoded_line
cdef str tile

cdef int counter=0 # Useful to know if it's the 3rd or 4th line of the current sequence in fastq.
with gzip.open(file_in, "rb") as f:
    for line in f:

        if counter%4==0: # first line of the sequence (obtain tail info)
            decoded_line = line.decode('utf-8')
            tile = decoded_line.split(':')[4]
            if tile != tile_specific and tile not in tiles.keys(): # tile_specific is mentiones elsewhere. 
                tiles[tile] = np.zeros(shape=(length, len(solexa_scores)+33), dtype=np.uint32)

            counter=0

        elif counter%3==0: # 3rd line of the sequence (obtain the qualities)
            decoded_line = line.decode('utf-8')
            for n in range(len(decoded_line)): #     enumerate(line.decode('utf-8')):
                tiles[tile][n, ord(decoded_line[n])] +=1
                
        counter+=1
```

In this second example, I don't know *a priori* the number of keys in the dictionary *tiles* and therefore, the numpy arrays will be declared and initialized during runtime (please, correct me if I am wrong or using the wrong terms).
Cython did not translate/compile when using the cython-declaration of the numpy arrays and hence, I left it as `tiles[tile] = np.zeros(shape=(length, len(solexa_scores)+33), dtype=np.uint32)`.
Since all other cython optimizations for code that is shared between the two snippets are fine, I believe that this numpy array declaration is the problem.

How should I fix that? [Here](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/memory_allocation.html), the manual indicates ways of dynamically allocate memory, but I don't know how this works with numpy arrays and if I should do it al all.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ignore the documentation about dynamically allocating memory. That's not what you want to do - it's very much at C level and you're handling Python objects.

You can easily reassign a variable typed as a Numpy array (or equally the newer typed memoryview) multiple times so that it refers to a different Numpy array. I suspect what you want is something like

```
# start of function
cdef np.ndarray[np.uint32_t, ndim=2] tile_array

# in "if counter%4==0":
if tile != tile_specific and tile not in tiles.keys(): # tile_specific is mentiones elsewhere. 
    tiles[tile] = np.zeros(shape=(length, len(solexa_scores)+33), dtype=np.uint32)
tile_array = tiles[tile]  # not a copy! Just two references to exactly the same object

# in "if counter%3==0"
tile_array[n, ord(decoded_line[n])] +=1
```

There's a small cost to `tile_array = tiles[tile]` just to do some type-checking, so it'll probably only be worthwhile if you use `tile_array` a few times between each assignment (it's hard to guess exactly what the threshold is, but time it against your current version).

Comment: I don't fully understand _why_ this is faster but from taking forever it now finishes in 17 seconds for the same input data. Thank you! I hope I can understand the concept of memoryview soon.

Comment: The thing Cython speeds up most is indexing individual elements of arrays: e.g. `tile_array[n, ord(decoded_line[n])] +=1`. This gets changed from two fairly slow Python calls (one to get and one to set the element) into one quick C operations. To do this Cython needs to know the type of the array. That's why it's significantly faster.